# Where is Marie Delacroix?

Tags: system-shock-2

Marie Delacroix has contacted me and told me to come find her in Cargo Bay A. However I've searched through both the shuttle bay cargo area (one is blocked off) and the main cargo hold without finding her. Where exactly is she?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an unfortunate lack of clarity in the dialogue.

She's in a different Bay A, which you'll get to much later. It, (and she) is impossible to miss at that time.

> Specifically, there is a second, separate set of Cargo Bays on Deck 6, at the shuttle hangar. After you blast open the doors to the shuttle bays, you can find Delacroix's body in the wreckage. Note that if you inspect her body and take the audiolog there, SHODAN will *not* be pleased. She will take 20 Cyber Modules from you and become audibly enraged. It's worth it for the scene though, IMO.

Comment: I just replayed System Shock 2 (still great) and found 10 cyber modules on Delacroix, and then SHODAN took away 10 cyber modules when I walked out of that area. So you actually end up drawing even. Note that if you can keep those ten cyber modules: see [this walkthrough by BBrush](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/185706-system-shock-2/faqs/27508), specifically the note about the "Instantaneous quantum relocation" psionic power.